# Sencha cmd not opening

Tags: extjs, cmd, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Hi I want to learn Sencha. I have basic knowledge of MVC. I have downloaded [sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) and [Sencha cmd](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download). I have extracted `sencha Touch` folder to my local. And I have installed Sencha cmd. But `Sencha cmd` is not working. When I click on `cmd` it automatically disappeared. What can I do now. I have installed `Sencha SDK Tool`.

Any one please help me out.

Comment: click on it?
its a command line.. open your console (command promt in windows) and type 'sencha'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a series of videos on how to prepare your computer for development here: http://extjs.eu/videos

Comment: Actually my video streaming is blocked. So I can't refer from that.

Comment: Thank you.. I will go through it

Answer (score 1):

After installing Sencha cmd in windows you need to set Environment variables.

1. Open start menu
2. Click on computer > Right click Properties.
3. In properties > click on Advance setting.
4. In Advance setting click on environment variable.
5. Here you select path and click on edit and add the path of the sench cmd.
6. Go back to cmd and run sencha.

Here you will get all the sencha details. if you get means sencha is installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to download the cmd(Which you have done). Then do the followings:

1. It is a zip file. Extract it.
2. Then you will get a .run file(If using ubuntu) or .exe file(In Windows).
3. Double click this file and install it. (For Ubuntu, first you have to change permission of this file to 777 using `chmod 777 .run/file/path` and then double click).

Now you can run `sencha` in terminal and check whether it has successfully been installed or not.

Comment: I am using windows. It is installed properly. After installation when I click on `cmd` it comes for 1 second and disappeared again

Answer (score 0):

Goto command promt and type sencha . if your sencha cmd is installed properly ,you will see data on your promt. if it says that sencha command not found,try reinstalling sencha cmd

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to open sencha cmd and sdk if you have correctly installed sencha cmd then go to command promt and type sencha if it's show version and other help command then it's properly installed.
then go to your sdk path and create app by sencha generate app app_name folder_name or path  where you want to create your application.

Answer (score 0):

A real case: Sencha v6.5.3.6 on Windows 10 professional x64. From CMD, you run

`C:\Users\computer_user_name\bin\Sencha\Cmd\sencha`

I must point out full path of sencha.exe for running.